# NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.jidesoft.swing.JideSwingUtilities

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, noclassdeffounderror, jide

Im working on my old project at the moment using jide libraries, I used netbeans as my IDE, it works fine when I was working with it in Windows 7 a year ago.

Currently I'm using OS X Mavericks and using netbeans 7.2.1, when I try to drag the component from the  palette manager i got this error.

Got anyone also encounter this?

EDIT:

Added the error log:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.jidesoft.swing.JideSwingUtilities
    at com.jidesoft.swing.Searchable.installListeners(Unknown Source)
    at com.jidesoft.swing.Searchable.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.jidesoft.swing.ComboBoxSearchable.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.jidesoft.swing.AutoCompletion.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.jidesoft.swing.AutoCompletionComboBox.createAutoCompletion(Unknown Source)
    at com.jidesoft.swing.AutoCompletionComboBox.initComponents(Unknown Source)
    at com.jidesoft.swing.AutoCompletionComboBox.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.CreationFactory.createDefaultInstance(CreationFactory.java:178)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.RADComponent.createBeanInstance(RADComponent.java:252)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.RADComponent.initInstance(RADComponent.java:191)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.MetaComponentCreator.initComponentInstance(MetaComponentCreator.java:1508)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.MetaComponentCreator.createVisualComponent(MetaComponentCreator.java:975)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.MetaComponentCreator.access$300(MetaComponentCreator.java:79)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.MetaComponentCreator$2.run(MetaComponentCreator.java:286)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormLAF$2.run(FormLAF.java:293)
    at org.openide.util.Mutex.doEventAccess(Mutex.java:1368)
    at org.openide.util.Mutex.readAccess(Mutex.java:327)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.FormLAF.executeWithLookAndFeel(FormLAF.java:276)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.MetaComponentCreator.precreateVisualComponent(MetaComponentCreator.java:283)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.MetaComponentCreator.precreateVisualComponent(MetaComponentCreator.java:306)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.HandleLayer$NewComponentDrag.init(HandleLayer.java:3367)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.HandleLayer$NewComponentDrag.<init>(HandleLayer.java:3359)
    at org.netbeans.modules.form.HandleLayer.mouseMoved(HandleLayer.java:2167)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseMotionEvent(Component.java:6550)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseMotionEvent(JComponent.java:3338)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6274)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4505)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at org.netbeans.core.TimableEventQueue.dispatchEvent(TimableEventQueue.java:159)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: Have a look at this [JIDE support forum post](http://www.jidesoft.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=14951)

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because your code is compiled against JDK1.6 but your runtime is not. In my case it was JRE1.7

You can fix this by making sure you JRE and JDK are the same versions.

For me, I changed my eclipse run config from 1.7 (default) to 1.6